# static_cast float to Enumeration

Tags: c++, dictionary, enums, floating-point, static-cast

Let's say that I have an enumeration:

```
enum FRACTION {
    WHOLE,
    HALF,
    THIRD,
    QUARTER,
    FRACTION_SIZE
};
```

Now I want to take a floating point denominator of a fraction and cast it, so I want:

- [`0.5F`, `1.5F`) to map to `WHOLE`
- [`1.5F`, `2.5F`) to map to `HALF`
- [`2.5F`, `3.5F`) to map to `THIRD`
- [`3.5F`, `4.5F`) to map to `QUARTER`

Given `float foo` I cannot do this:

```
static_cast<FRACTION>(round(foo))
```

Because I get the error:

> error C2440: `static_cast`: cannot convert from `float` to `FRACTION`

I can do 2 `static_cast`s: `static_cast<FRACTION>(static_cast<int>(round(foo)))` Or I could probably work out a `map` solution with `lower_bound`. But both of those seem ugly. Does [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) not have a provision for more direct conversion?

Comment: `FRACTION(int(round(foo)))`, using constructors (A *provision* of **C++**), without casting?

Comment: Just put `static_cast<FRACTION>(static_cast<int>(round(foo)))` in a function and the ugliness disappears.  C++ does not have a built in mechanism for this.

Comment: @Ruks I mean... that is essentially the same thing?

Comment: @JonathanMee `#define CONVERT_TO_FRACTION(a) FRACTION(int(round(a)))` at the beginning and use `CONVERT_TO_FRACTION(foo)` instead, without even needing functions and removing *ugliness*.

Answer (score 3):

You want a function to do it:

```
FRACTION classifyDenominator(float denominator) {
  assert(denominator >= 0.5f && denominator < 4.5f);
  denominator -= 0.5f;
  return static_cast<FRACTION>(int(denominator));
}
```